# Drastically increase size of array

Tags: vb.net

I have an array in visual studio (vb). I have declared its size like below, how can I increase its size? I'm looking to a length of more than 100000.

```
Dim rawData(DataGridView4.Rows.Count, DataGridView4.Columns.Count - 1) As Object
' Copy the column names to the first row of the object array
For col = 0 To DataGridView4.Columns.Count - 1
    rawData(0, col) = DataGridView4.Columns(col).HeaderText.ToUpper
Next
```

Comment: You can't actually increase the size of an array. What you can do is use `ReDim Preserve` or `Array.Resize` to create a new array of the desired size and copy the contents of the old one across.

Comment: i have more than 100000 data which i need to export in excel but if use it shows me error and i guess it is because of ROWDATA 's size ..can  you suggest anything?

Comment: You can use datatable for example. You add rows to it just like dgv.

Comment: Can't suggest anything, because you've not included anything about the error in your question. You can't ask a question in comments. Instead, [edit] your post and ask the question there.

Comment: i want to use rawData in loop how can i  declare it and use it in loop?